# How to Rank in order without skipping in MDX query

Tags: mdx, cube, mdx-query, multidimensional-cube

I have a MDX query that Rank clients but in the WHERE Clause I added

```
With Member [Measures].[Rank2] As 
IIF([DimClient].[Client].CurrentMember.member_caption = [ClientBenchmark].[ClientGroup].currentMember.member_caption,0,
    Rank ([DimClient].[Client].CurrentMember,(Order ([DimClient].[Client].[Client],[Measures].[Vol], BDesc)))
    )

Select {​​[Measures].[Vol]
,[Measures].[Rank2]}​​ On Columns,
 {​​[DimClient].[Client].[Client]}​​ on Rows

From [cube] 
where [ClientBenchmark].[Client].&[ATTS];
```

When executed it returns

[image]

DimClient and ClientBenchmark dimensions are unrelated in the cube.

However, I want to achieve the screenshot below

[image]

Note the ranking didn't skip.
I will appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try an additional `FILTER` inside the `RANK`?

```
With 
Member [Measures].[Rank2] As 
IIF(
  [DimClient].[Client].CurrentMember.member_caption 
     = [ClientBenchmark].[ClientGroup].currentMember.member_caption
  ,0
  ,Rank (
      [DimClient].[Client].CurrentMember,
      (
          Order (
             filter(
               EXISTING ([DimClient].[Client].[Client] ),
               [DimClient].[Client].CurrentMember.member_caption 
                    <> [ClientBenchmark].[ClientGroup].currentMember.member_caption
             ),
             [Measures].[Vol], 
             BDesc
           )
       )   
    )
)
Select 
{​​[Measures].[Vol]
,[Measures].[Rank2]}​​ On Columns,
 {​​[DimClient].[Client].[Client]}​​ on Rows

From [cube] 
where [ClientBenchmark].[Client].&[ATTS];
```